# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.github.fge.jackson.JsonLoader

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I am using github project  '[json-schema-validator](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator)' and getting below error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.github.fge.jackson.JsonLoader
at ****************.getJsonNode(Service.java:63)
at ****************.getSchemaNode(Service.java:69)
at ****************.isJsonValid(Service.java:93)
at ****************.requestToSectionJSON(Controller.java:477)
```

I added jar files same as the github project.. 
but I don't know why it keeps getting this lib error.

(ignore *** part. it just my package name)

- jackson-coreutils 1.9
- json-schema-core 1.2.10
- jackson-core 2.9.6
- jackson-databind 2.9.6
- jackson-annotation 2.9.6
- msg-simple 1.1
- btf 1.2
- GUABA 16.0.1
- json-schema-validator 2.2.10
- joda-time 2.9.7
- uri-template 0.9
- RHINO 1.7.7.1
- libphonenumber 8.0.0
- jsr305 3.0.1
- activation 1.1.1
- mailapi 1.4.3
- jotp simple 5.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the times this error happens if you have wrong version of jars at runtime. Make sure you are using proper version of `jackson-coreutils.jar` (same version you used while compiling the code).

Comment: my new error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/github/fge/jsonschema/core/processing/CachingProcessor

Comment: @Solar If this answer solved your original problem, mark the answer and post a new question with your new error. That is how StackOverflow Q & A system works.  Good luck!